# Proving a sequence (x$_n$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Back again! help is much appreciate as I seem to have found myself stuck and pretty much turned in a blank worksheet to my professor. He says these types of problems will be on our final, and I have no clue where to start.

Define the sequence (x$_n$) in $R$ by x$_0$:= 1 and x$_n$$_+$$_1$:= x$_n$ + 1/x$_n$. Use any relevant theorems about limits of certain sequences and continuity, thusly proving the seq. (x$_n$) is unbounded.

Comment: Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Ratio_test ?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty obvious that your sequence is strictly increasing so it either is unbounded or convergent.
Let assume that $x_n \to l \in \mathbb{R}$ then we have $l=l+\frac{1}{l}$ which is impossible so $(x_n)$ is unbounded

Answer (score 1):

An unusual approach, but it focuses on the logarithmic growth of $x_n$, henec linear growth of $\exp(x_n)$:

Using $\exp t\ge 1+t$ we can show $1\le x_n\le n+1\le \exp(x_n)$ by induction:

The case $n=1$ is clear: $1\le 1\le 2\le e$.

Assume $1\le x_{n-1}\le n\le \exp(x_{n-1})$.
Then $$\begin{align}\exp(x_{n})&=\exp(x_{n-1}+\tfrac1{x_{n-1}})\\
&=\exp(x_{n-1})\exp(\tfrac 1{x_{n-1}})\\
&\ge n\cdot (1+\tfrac 1{x_n})\\
&\ge n\cdot (1+\tfrac 1n)
\\&=n+1\end{align}$$
and
$$x_n=x_{n-1}+\frac1{x_{n-1}}\le n+\frac 11=n+1 $$
and $$ x_n=x_{n-1}+\frac1{x_{n-1}}\ge 1+\frac1n\ge 1$$
We conclude that $\exp(x_n)\to\infty$ nd hence also $x_n\to\infty$